# Why dropzone is not configured correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am working on an AngularJS project.
I'm using this boiler project https://github.com/gothinkster/angularjs-realworld-example-app.git
which supports ES6.
I'm using DropzoneJS as a Directive but it could not implement.
My custom directive code looks like.

**drop-zone.directive.js**

```
import { Dropzone } from "dropzone";
function dropZone() {
  'ngInject';

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        action: "@",
        autoProcess: "=?",
        callBack: "&?",
        dataMax: "=?",
        mimetypes: "=?",
        message: "@?"
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.warn(scope.dataMax);

      // Autoprocess the form
      if (scope.autoProcess != null && scope.autoProcess == "false") {
          scope.autoProcess = false;
      } else {
          scope.autoProcess = true;
      }

      // Max file size
      if (scope.dataMax == null) {
          scope.dataMax = Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.maxFilesize;
      } else {
          scope.dataMax = parseInt(scope.dataMax);
      }

      // Message for the uploading
      if (scope.message == null) {
          scope.message = Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictDefaultMessage;
      }

      element.dropzone({
          url: scope.action,
          maxFilesize: scope.dataMax,
          paramName: "file",
          acceptedFiles: scope.mimetypes,
          maxThumbnailFilesize: scope.dataMax,
          dictDefaultMessage: scope.message,
          autoProcessQueue: scope.autoProcess,
          success: function (file, response) {
              if (scope.callBack != null) {
                  scope.callBack({response: response});
              }
          }
      });
    }
  };
}

export default dropZone;
```

**Index.html**

```
<div drop-zone
                action="/file/upload/"
                call-back="myCallBackMethod(response)"
                data-max="10"
                auto-process="false"
                message="Drop file here or click to select"
                mimetypes="'.doc,.docx,.pages,.pdf,.odt'"
                >
            </div>
```

and Error is
[image: Console Error]

Comment: You are trying to invoke dropzone in an unsupported way. Pass the element as the first argument to the dropzone constructor. https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics

Comment: @BlueWater86
I need to use dropzone in Repeat directive in a Form.
I don't want to initialize the dropzone explicit each time for an element.
That's why I looking for a custom directive that will to it's job in a loop...

Comment: So store the single instance on first run then and return the stored instance after that.